# @font-face nested within @media does not work in Firefox 3.5 and IE8

Tags: css, font-face

**Update**: Looks like I got caught up in a correlation that was not in fact the cause of the problem. Problem was actually an unrelated issue in how CSS files were deployed. See my answer below for details.

<del>I have @font-face working well in WebKit (Safari and Chrome) and Opera, but not in Firefox 3.5 or IE 8.</del>

Per recommendations by Google and others, I serve all static assets, including CSS, from a separate domain from my main site. **If I serve everything from the same domain, it works fine in all browsers** (note: this means that answers about CSS syntax are useless. I already have all of that figured out and working great. This is ONLY about the cross-domain issues).

If I serve CSS and font files from my static assets domain, and have the static assets server set the appropriate [access-control header](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control) (Access-Control-Allow-Origin), which *should* work, it works everywhere except FF 3.5 and IE.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>The best answer I've discovered so far, in hopes that it helps someone else:</del>

<del>As far as I can tell, the key issue is whether the CSS file (not the font file) is loaded cross-domain. If I load the CSS file with the @font-face declarations from my static assets domain, nothing I do will make the fonts work in FF or IE, regardless of the access control headers. If I load the CSS file from the same domain as the page, or I just move my @font-face declarations into a style block in the page head, then it works in all browsers (I can even load the font files cross-domain as long as I have the access control header set).</del>

<del>To summarize: AFAICT, FF 3.5 and IE 8 will refuse to honor @font-face declarations in a cross-domain-loaded CSS file, no matter what.</del>

<del>I would love to be corrected on this if anyone knows better and can point out what else I might be doing wrong.</del>

Indeed, I was wrong. It turns out the CSS-compressor we were using for deploying assets to be served from the dedicated domain was wrapping the entire chunk of CSS with "@media screen { ... }". I carefully compared the @font-face rules to be sure the compressor didn't mess with them, but never checked the very beginning and end of the CSS file to catch that wrapping. When I switched to serving same-domain, that wrapping didn't happen.

As it turns out, IE and Firefox do not honor @font-face declarations wrapped inside @media: Safari, Chrome and Opera do.

Sigh.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest looking at [this IEBlog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/07/21/font-embedding-on-the-web.aspx), which describes how you do font embedding on IE. No, that doesn't match the CSS3 way, and no, you don't have any other way to do it in IE using @font-face.

It might be worth noting that Microsoft submitted the EOT approach to the W3C in a move to get it standardized, and W3C has [expressed interest](http://www.w3.org/Submission/2008/01/Comment) in that course of action.

Comment: See my edited clarification above. As I said originally, if I put everything on the same domain it all works to my complete satisfaction in all browsers. This means that answers which don't specifically address the cross-domain issue are irrelevant here. The article you link to says nothing about the cross-domain issues. Sorry for the downvote, but I want to make sure the relevant answers stay at the top.

Answer (score -2):

This link helped me a lot: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/becoming-a-font-embedding-master

Unfortunately, I was sorely disappointed with the quality of the text from most of the fonts I wanted to try.  I couldn't decide if some fonts weren't anti-aliasable or not but the results weren't satisfying and I still use image replacement.

Comment: See my edited clarification above. As I said originally, if I put everything on the same domain it all works to my complete satisfaction in all browsers. This means that answers which don't specifically address the cross-domain issue are irrelevant here. The article you link to says nothing about the cross-domain issues. Sorry for the downvote, but I want to make sure the relevant answers stay at the top.

Comment: I'd like to see the page if the results are satisfactory.  Would you mind posting a sample?

Comment: I'll gladly post a link to the site when it goes live (within a week), but can't until then. If you're interested in the design side of things, I think that's what you're looking for. I'd also like to post a simple pared-down demonstration of the cross-domain issues, but don't have time just now.

Comment: Guess I'm a little late getting back here, but fwiw the site in question is http://www.thesteelwheels.com, if you're interested in seeing the results achieved with font-face.